# differentiate if executed at startup or later (python)

Tags: python

I want to make the script react depending on when it is executed, i want it to do something when it is executed when Windows starts and something else here it is executed by a user or another scrypt after startup

i tried if 'STARTUP' in os.environ: but it didnt work

Comment: _i tried if 'STARTUP' in os.environ_ Why did you think that would work?

Comment: How do the script is executed at startup? Maybe pass an argument that says it is run at startup?

Comment: @JohnGordon i asked the question to chat gpt and it told me to do that

Comment: @buran the .py is in windows startup folder

Comment: Why not to make 2 different scripts?

Comment: Regarding "when Windows starts", you can schedule tasks in the Windows task manager using python.

Comment: Maybe you could check the identity of the user account that is executing the code, and if it is the Windows system user, you could assume it is running at startup?

Answer (score 1):

To elaborate on my comment, you can pass a flag argument and check that argument during execution to determine whether the script run at startup.
Something like this:

```
import argparse
parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
parser.add_argument('--startup', action='store_true')
args = parser.parse_args()


if args.startup:
    input('The script executed during startup. Press key to continue...')
else:
    input('The script executed after startup. Press key to continue...')
```

This is example using `argparse` from Standard Library, but same can be acomplished using any CLI framework like `Click`.

Then in the Startup folder add a shortcut with following target

```
 <path to python executable> <path to python script> --startup
```

If using Task scheduler, pass the `--startup` flag accordingly.

That said, there is not enough information what the difference is when the script run during startup and otherwise. It may be better to have 2 different scripts or take completely different approach, depending on circumstances.

Comment: In addition to the above, we can look at the script name to decide what to do next, sort of `import sys; if "something" in sys.argv[0]: ...` and make a link under a different name to the original script in the startup folder.

Comment: @Vitalizzare, the name of the shortcut is not shown in sys.argv. You see the actual name of the script

Comment: Oops, what a pity! Didn't know about this side of labels in Windows :-(